# How to resolve Anypoint studion 7 errors?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have just installed anypoint studio 7.3.4

When i create a new mule project i got two default errors

[image]

I have dependency file as below

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

I'm completely struct, How to proceed ?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections --> Change "Active Providers" from Native to Direct then restart the workspace.

Comment: socket error got resolved but HTTP error is still there